# How to set a default value in an input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState([]);

const handleUserInfo = (id) => {
        fetch(`https://602e7c2c4410730017c50b9d.mockapi.io/users/${id}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setUserInfo(data)) 
}
```

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={userInfo?.profile?.firstName + userInfo?.profile?.lastName} className="form-control bg-light" id="exampleInputName" aria-describedby="name"></input>
```

I am expecting to see both firstname and last name in that input field with a gap between first name and last name. But I see NAN because I tried to add firstname and lastname using plus (+)
The NAN doesn't show up if I only want to see the first name when the default value is defaultValue={userInfo?.profile?.firstName}

Comment: Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) with concatenation is going to end up with unexpected values when the property access fails, but receiving `NaN` seems odd, i'd expect `firsnameundefined` (you aren't adding a space). You'll need to post a sample of your data or better a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more concrete help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Input's `defaultValue` is set on the initial load of your component. Your request is asynchronous which means that you are probably getting the result after the initial load. So you need to transform your component into a controlled component. Meaning, you will have to create a state that will hold the input value as well as to listen on the onChange event and alter your state to reflect the changes. You can check the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) for more info on forms and their behavior.

```
export default function ExampleComponent() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  React.useEffect( () => {
    handleUserInfo(5)
  }, [])

  const handleUserInfo = (id) => {
    fetch(`https://602e7c2c4410730017c50b9d.mockapi.io/users/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          setInputValue(`${data?.profile?.firstName} ${data?.profile?.lastName}`)
          setUserInfo(data)
        } )
  }
  
  return (
    <input 
      type="text"
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
      className="form-control bg-light" 
      id="exampleInputName" 
      aria-describedby="name"
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo when you are trying to display `default value`, try to change
`userInfo?.profile?.firstName + userInfo?.profile?.lastlName` to
`userInfo?.profile?.firstName + userInfo?.profile?.lastName`.
(lastName was misspelled incorrectly).
also it's a better way to use template literals

Comment: defaultValue={userInfo?.profile?.firstName + userInfo?.profile?.lastName}   I tried this. Still I get NAN